# Save results of a Access query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-insert

I have a query in Access which does some calculations which (I think) can't be done in SQL Server directly because of a vital local table in Access. I used to use a append query in Access to save this data. I'm now working on replacing the Access database with a SQL Server database.

Is there a way to get the Access query results saved in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please post your trial code

Comment: @JoeTaras I don't have any trail code. I tried a passtrough query in Access but that doens't work because of the local table in Access. I have no idea were to start off from this point

Comment: Rather than just saving results in SQL server, why not move the "vital local table" to SQL server, then do all calculations in SQL server?

You can  still have it as a linked table in Access if there are other dependencies.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping It's a application used by multiple users which all have their own variations. In the local table is saved who is in the application a.t.m. Everyone has it's own copy of this. If I use your solution it would constantly be overwritten and the application wont work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access can directly execute `INSERT INTO` queries to SQL server tables.

The easiest way is to use a linked table, but if that's undesirable for whatever reason, you can use the connection string in the query. It has to be a valid string for DAO (e.g. ODBC string starting with `ODBC;`).

```
INSERT INTO [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;].[My Table] (Column1, Column2)
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM SomeQuery
```

Comment: tnx Erik. No idea why my original code didn't work because I only switched from local table to linked SQL Server table. But it's working now.